# c# retrieving type of array element using reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

How do I instantiate an array property using Reflection based on the code below?

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {
      foreach(var property in GetType().GetProperties())
      {
         if (property.PropertyType.IsArray)
         { 
            // the line below creates a 2D array of type Bar.  How to fix?
            var array = Array.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType, 0);
            property.SetValue(this, array, null);
         }
      }
   }
   public Bar[] Bars {get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first parameter of [`Array.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb3cfh7k.aspx) expects the *element type* of the array. You pass the entire property type, which is, as you have just found out by checking `property.PropertyType.IsArray`, an array type (specifically, `Bar[]` - i.e. an array of `Bar` elements).

To get the *element type* of an array type, use its [`GetElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) method:

```
var array = Array.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType.GetElementType(), 0);
```

*I suppose you will replace the zero passed to the second argument with a higher number when required, unless you actually want only empty arrays.*